# Service to Service Authentication with Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to use Keycloak as Identity Access Management. Creating client & authenticating user is quite okay between Spring Boot and Keycloak. What I am trying to do is authentication and authorization between Spring Boot microservices. The scenario is as follow.

1. There are two microservices: service A and service B.
2. Service A has one non-authenticated api route (api 1) which needs to communicate with authenticated api (api 2) on service B.
3. Api 2 would like to know which services are requesting and have certain access.

I have tried using service account and search online but no luck with Keycloak. :(

Please help me. Thanks